# Return array from JSON file with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON file that contains the following:
[{name:joe,number:4},{name:ralph,number:76}]

Simply put, I'm trying to create a function that returns that as an array:

```
function createArray(){
    x = $.getJSON("/names.json", function(json) {
        var myArray = [];
        $.each(json, function() {   
            myArray.push(json);
        });
        return myArray;
    });
    return x;
}
```

This is not working, I'm not sure what part of it doesnt make sense

Comment: Have you tried debugging? If you add an `alert(json);` before the `var myArray ... `, does it tell you it's an object? Or is there an error server side perhaps?

Comment: does it even return anything?

Comment: It says its returning an object, and the array is in the "responseText"

Comment: check it using the console. do a `console.log(json)` in the callback

Comment: in the console log, the object just contains the names and numbers

Answer (score 2):

You are doing an asynchronous request. $.getJSON does not return the result of your callback.

You need to pass a callback into your `createArray` function. Also, if your JSON data is already an array, you don't need to process the response data.

```
function createArray(cb){
  $.getJSON("/names.json", cb);
}
```

So for example you'd change this:

```
var myArray = createArray();
// Process myArray
```

into this:

```
createArray(function(myArray) {
  // Process myArray
});
```

The problem is that you can't just assign the result of a network request. When you call getJSON, you start a network request, but after the request starts, the JS will keep running other stuff. The get the result of an asynchronous request, you need to use a callback that will process that data and do something with it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... How do I call the function then to get the array? I have nothing to put in the callback..

Comment: Any logic you have that uses that data would be put into the callback function. If you give a bit of context of how you are calling this, I can give an example.

Comment: I just want to create a variable in a different function that has the array.. i.e. var myArray = createArray();

Comment: @Elliot I added a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Like loganfsmyth said, you're not taking into account that $.getJSON is asynchronous, and it's not going to return what you think it is (it actually returns a jqXHR Object.  Write your code to handle the asynchronous nature using closures:

```
function createArray(cb){
    $.getJSON("/names.json", function(json) {
        var myArray = [];
        $.each(json, function() {   
            myArray.push(json);
        });
        cb(myArray);
    });
}

createArray(function(array) {
    //your array is available here
    console.log(array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your keys and values should be Strings

```
[{"name":"joe", "number":4},{"name":"ralph", "number":76}]
```

and this

```
$.each(json, function() {   
     myArray.push(json);
});
```

should become

```
$.each(json, function(key, val) {
      if(myArray[key] == undefined)
      {     myArray[key] = new Array();
      }
      myArray[key].push(val);
});
```

Comment: I want the array to be the same as in the JSON file though, shouldn't I need both the key and the val?

Comment: THen you are looking at Javascript two dimensional arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, your function will return a [promise object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR), but never the json response itself. The response will be available from the promise only after the request is complete (which is *not immediately after function return* because the request is asynchronous).

Why don't you just use the json from the callback? I mean this:

```
function createArray(){
    $.getJSON("/names.json", function(json) {
        // Whatever you need to do with your json,
        // do it here. This code will run after  
        // createArray returns. And you can't
        // return anything from here, it's useless.
        // Actually, you don't even need the outer
        // createArray function.
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you get from 'json' is an array.
try this,

```
var ar = [{
    "name": "joe",
    "number": "4"},
{
    "name": "ralph",
    "number": "76" }];


alert(ar[0].name);​
```

This would alert the name "joe".
`ar[0]` is the first element of the array and in your case this is an object with properties `name` and `number`. You can get/set them in normal way.

```
    var myArray = [];
    $.getJSON("/names.json", function(json) {

            myarray=json;
    });
```

Now`myArray` is an array with your Objects.